# Having trouble getting a transaction to validate with my Plutus contract

Tags: validator

```
validator :: BuiltinData -> BuiltinData -> BuiltinData -> ()
validator _ _ ctx =
  if paidTo seller then () else traceError "NFT locked until seller is paid."
    where
      paidTo x = valuePaidTo txInfo (PubKeyHash x) `gt` minAmount
      txInfo = scriptContextTxInfo $ unsafeFromBuiltinData ctx
      minAmount = assetClassValue (assetClass adaSymbol adaToken) 50
      seller1 = <public key hash of seller1_addr>
```

This is the basic validator. It compiles to PLC code and I can lock the NFT to the script address, however when I try to build a transaction to spend it:

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
--babbage-era \
--testnet-magic 2 \
--tx-in $script_utxo \
--tx-in-script-file $script_file \
--tx-in-inline-datum-present \
--tx-in-redeemer-value $redeemer \
--tx-in-collateral $buyer_utxo \
--tx-out "$(cat $seller1_addr) + 100000000 lovelace" \
--tx-out "$(cat $buyer_addr) + 1 $NFT" \
--change-address $(cat $buyer_addr) \
--protocol-params-file proto_params \
--out-file buyer_unsigned.tx
```

It fails with the following:

```
the script for transaction input 0 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The machine terminated because of an error, either from a built-in function or from an explicit use of 'error'.
Script debugging logs: NFT locked until seller1 paid.
```

Is there something incorrect here? What am I missing?